# I'm making a single GET request on page load; how can I get the response data into different single file components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

First I'm making the GET request and creating the Vue instance:

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';


let getData = () => {  // currently unused - need to get promise return value into components
  let url = '';
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      return data;
    }
}


new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Then I'm creating the top-level component that attaches to my index.html:

`App.Vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Badge></Badge>
    <Card></Card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Badge from './components/Badge.vue';
import Card from './components/Card.vue';

export default {
  name: 'app',
//props: ['data'],  //  unused, possible solution?
  components: {
    Badge,
    Card
  }
}
</script>
```

And then `Badge.vue` and `Card.vue` are both components that (need to) display different data from the fetch in `main.js`

---

I've tried using props to pass data from `main.js` `->` `App.vue` `->` `Card.vue` but I wasn't able to figure out how to do that with this code in `main.js`:

```
new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

I suspect `render` may be my problem; I'm using it from an example I followed in a tutorial - I'm pretty sure it's for the live webserver I'm using when I run `vue-cli-service serve` so maybe this is as simple as doing things differently to send props to `App.vue`

However, it seems like passing data through props this way is a *bad idea* and that I should be doing things differently, I just don't know what that would be, so I'm hoping there may be a more elegant solution. I'm only making a single ajax call which hopefully simplifies things, but it seems like using props this way can get too messy if I start adding more components.

Comment: the getData function should declare in app.vue , then the data should be in  app.vue data props

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `getData` to the `App.vue`

`App.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Badge></Badge>
    <Card></Card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Badge from './components/Badge.vue';
import Card from './components/Card.vue';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: () => ({ // To store data in App.vue
    someData: []
  }),
  components: {
    Badge,
    Card
  },
  created: {
      this.getData(); // Call getData function when the component is created
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
        // Making reference to component instance since we can't access `this` inside arrow function
        const self = this;

        let url = "";
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                self.someData = data;
            }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If you need to share data between multiple components, then i highly recommend you to use Vuex instead.